# background-clip: padding-box not working (background)

Tags: html, css

Hullo!

Look at the following code:

```css
body{
  background:#000;
}

#banner{
  height:80px;
  position:relative;
  
  background:red;
  border-radius:3px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#banner::before{
  /*make pseudo-element take up all space*/
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  
  /*tricky part*/
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #1d2021, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  text
</div>
```

On all browsers I tested, the background bleeds out (you can see red spots in the corners, on the left). When I searched for a solution, it said I should use something called `padding-box` but it doesn't seem to work here.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature.

No but for real, if you zoom into the code snippet's output given in the question, the red 'outline' disappears. This is probably an issue with browsers having a slight precision error while making the border radius, causing the pseudo to bleed out despite overflow being set to hidden.

Comment: @RoboMop on my end it still shows up pretty vividly.

Comment: Did you zoom in natively with a touchpad or by changing the chrome zoom settings? I'm using a laptop and the difference is remarkable

Comment: @RoboMop CTRL+. Im using firefox, but the same bug can be reproduced in the latest version of chrome.

Comment: Also seen on Edge Windows 10 and Safari iPadIOS 14 (pinch zoom)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to the linear gradient. If you remove that and set background-color of the pseudo element to anything instead you still get the dotted corners. If you remove the overflow: hidden though the dotted corners disappear. BTW padding-box is obsolete according to [link]https://caniuse.com Using border-box didn't seem to make any difference. Nor did setting border-width: 0;

Comment: @AHaworth damn, thanks for trying anyways man. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: It's not even to do with pseudo elements - if you remove the pseudo element but lay another div with black background  over the top of the red one you get the same effect. Aaargh. As it's dots and not even a 1px wide arc it looks as though it has something to do with the way screen pixels are drawn and their positions calculated.

Comment: It is not seen on a pre-retina type display (an old iPad). So looks as though it is to do with the mapping of physical screen pixels to CSS ones - there being 4 physical to 1CSS pixel in most modern devices. It's as if one gets 'left behind' on the curves.

Comment: @AHaworth i was able to get the graphical bug in android 2.3 and ios 4 as well. Both devices I tested have really low DPI

Comment: I guess my theory bites the dust then. Try the div as a large circle, border radius 50% width and height 600px say. The pattern of dots varies with the position, none at extremities left/right and top/bottom, densest at 45 degrees, and symmetric and consistent.

Comment: @AHaworth do you think its a cross browser bug or is it due to my code? A cross browser bug would be very unlikely.

Comment: @AHaworth alright, so as it turns out, a simple DIV with a background image+gradient causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround:

```css
body{
  background:#000;
}

#banner{
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #1d2021, grey);
  height:80px;
  
  border-radius:15px;
  overflow:hidden;
  
  position:relative;
}   

#banner::before{
  content:'';
  background:red;
  opacity:.2;
  
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  text
</div>
```

Above workaround has a few downsides:

1. Image lacks in clarity cause of `opacity:.2`
2. From what I saw here, the ::before element has to contain the background image

Answer (score 0):

It appears (though not proven) that the dots are made up of just part of the 'normal' pixel when the system is calculating positioning rounding the corner. This is very apparent if you draw a much larger banner and make it square and circular (border-radius: 50%).

For the immediate problem here we can get the effect desired, without the little red dots, by keeping the pseudo element background as-is but changing the banner background from red to a linear gradient:

```
background:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 3px, red 3.1px, red 100%);
```

This cheats by drawing only transparent color for the first 3 (CSS) pixels. At least on the experiments I did the (my) human eye could not tell that there was a 3px where red was not being mixed with the top grey color. If that does become apparent though we could put in a more sophisticated linear-gradient to have transparent only as the top and bottom 3px squares, but I doubt if that is necessary.

Here's the complete snippet:

```css
body{
  background:#000;
}

#banner{
  height:80px;
  position:relative;
  
  background:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 3px, red 3.1px, red 100%);
  border-radius:3px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#banner::before{
  /*make pseudo-element take up all space*/
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  
  /*tricky part*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1d2021, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  text
</div>
```

Comment: What I ended up doing actually is using a pseudo element in the top left to hide the pixels. It works especially well when the border-radius is small and the gradient is large.